# Mysqli advice, 1 or 2 queries with maybe concat()

Tags: php, mysqli, concatenation

Thank you for the time reading my post.

I have 2 tables users and config.

The **users table** as several fields:
id, client_id, site_id, username, email, password
From the users table I'm getting all users that have a specific client id that is passed via $_SESSION, and it works fine, I get all users from a specific client_id

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE client_id = '".$_SESSION['c_id']."'
```

This returns example with 2 users:

```
++id++ ++client_id++ ++site_id++ ++username++ ++email++ ++password++
1        1             1,2         test1        1@1.com   pass
2        1             1           test2        2@1.com   pass
```

From the config table I need to get the meta (the Site Name comma separated) via site_id passed from users and via name field that specifies the meta (s_name). The desired result from this table is the meta in 1 row maybe using concat().
The **config table** as several fields:

```
++id++ ++client_id++ ++site_id++ ++name++ ++meta++
  1      1             1           s_name   Site 1 Name
  2      1             2           s_name   Site 2 Name
```

The final result would be the users table replacing the site_id with the config table meta field comma separated

```
++id++ ++client_id++ ++site_id++   ++username++ ++email++ ++password++
1        1             Site 1 name,  test1        1@1.com    pass
                       Site 2 Name 
2        1             Site 1 name   test2        2@1.com    pass
```

Advices are appreciated, should I use 1 complex mysqli query or 2 queries, with 2 loops?

So far I'm attempting with 2 queries, the I can not get the second query to concat the site name comma separated:

```
$client_id_query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE client_id = '".$_SESSION['c']."'";

$client_id_result = mysqli_query($hotelconnection->hotelconn,$client_id_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($client_id_result) > 0){

while ($row_client_id = mysqli_fetch_array($client_id_result) ){

$explode_user_site_id = $row_client_id['site_id'];

$explode_user_site_id = explode(',', $explode_user_site_id);

foreach($explode_user_site_id as $unique_id){

$site_name_query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta SEPARATOR ',') AS website_name FROM config WHERE name = 'website_name' AND client_id = '".$row_client_id['client_id']."' AND site_id = '".$unique_id."'";

$site_name_result = mysqli_query($hotelconnection->hotelconn,$site_name_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($site_name_result) > 0){
while ($row_site_name = mysqli_fetch_array($site_name_result) ){

// Result is not concated in 1 row
++id++ ++client_id++ ++site_id++   ++username++ ++email++ ++password++
1        1             Site 1 name  test1        1@1.com    pass
1        1             Site 2 Name  test1        1@1.com    pass
2        1             Site 1 name  test2        2@1.com    pass

}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient solution but works.
**Removing the site_id foreach wich was creating 3 total loops** and making the config loop FIND_IN_SET the side_ids results in a single row per user concating the site names comma separated.

```
$site_name_query = SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta SEPARATOR ', ') AS website_name FROM config WHERE name = 'website_name' AND client_id = '".$row_client_id['client_id']."' AND FIND_IN_SET(site_id, '".$row_client_id['site_id']."')";
```